# PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_NN'

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle19c, oracle-spatial

I'm trying to SDO_NN or Oracle SQL Developer. I've run the query on one server and it worked fine. I then copied it to a different server and changed just the table names since the second server has the same tables but slightly different names, the columns are the same but in the new server it is throwing an error.

Apart from changing the table names everything else is the same in the query. The only thing I can thing of is different versions of Oracle on the two servers. It is working on a server running Oracle 19c EE but failing on the server running 11g EE.

Query:

```sql
select WBAN,
       STATION_NAME,
       EXCH_NAME,
       sdo_nn_distance (1) distance_in_km,
       GEOM_LAT_LON
FROM   SCHEMA.WEATHER_DATA,
       SCHEMA.EXCH_GEOM 
WHERE  SDO_NN(WEATHER_DATA.GEOM_LAT_LON, EXCH_GEOM.GEOM, 'sdo_num_res=1 distance=40 unit=kilometer') ='TRUE'
ORDER BY EXCH_NAME
```

Error:

```
ORA-29900: operator binding does not exist
ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SDO_NN'
29900. 00000 -  "operator binding does not exist"
*Cause:    There is no binding for the current usage of the operator.
*Action:   Change the operator arguments to match any of the existing
           bindings or add a new binding to the operator.
Error at Line: 221 Column: 7
```

I'm trying a spatial query to identify the nearest entry in the EXCH_GEOM table to the WEATHER_DATA table within 40km.

Comment: Are you using SDE? If so, do you need to use `SDE.sdo_nn_distance (1), [...] WHERE  SDE.SDO_NN( [...]`

Comment: Having trouble replicating the error [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-1LWeJ81)

Comment: I wonder if this is because of the `sdo_nn_distance (1)` in your select list. That only works if you provide the same context id (`1`) in your SDO_NN: `SDO_NN(WEATHER_DATA.GEOM_LAT_LON, EXCH_GEOM.GEOM, 'sdo_num_res=1 distance=40 unit=kilometer',1)`

Comment: Thank you for replies.

I've tried SDE and adding context id (1) to the variables but still no luck. The system didn't recognise SDE as an option and gave the original error when I added the context id

Comment: That should actually give you this error in 19c: `ORA-29908: missing primary invocation for ancillary operator`. But it could be that 11g gives a different error. I have no 11g database available for testing.